# Where should i put a new sql query function Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony-3.4

I just started to work in symfony 3.4 and i'm pretty lost.

I want to make a `CRUD` for Products.The products table have multiple columns(name,description,CATEGORY_ID).

In create page, for this category_id, i want to make a select with the names of the categories that are stored in another table(id and category_name).

For this i need to select all the categories, but i don't really know how to do that.

I worked in codeigniter before and there i would make a `function` `getAllCategories` in `category_model` and i would call it in Controller.But here...i don't know how to do this.

Can you explain to me please how this should work?Where should i make the sql functions?

Answer (score 0):

Your seem lost on things that are very basic for Symfony. 
You probably have to start reading a lot and from the start.

You have two parts that you have to cover.

One is doctrine and how you can declare entities and manage them with the entity manager, and the second is Forms and how you can use them to render your form (including the foreign entity relation), to handle and validate your submitted data, and to pass the validated data to the database through the entity manager.

Your example is pretty simple, so it should be very easy to follow a tutorial while modifying it to fit your code.